# Mutually referencing class deadlock

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two SQLAlchemy class declarations that refer to each other so the first one gives an error because the second one is not yet declared.

The records in `Key` with `key_type_id == 4` are references from one `Entity` to a parent `Entity` via the `parent_entity_id`.

To define the relationship in `Entity` that collects all the child entities I need to add a backref, but that references `key` which is declared later.

```
class Entity(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'entity'
    entity_id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    ...
    children = db.relationship(
        'Entity', secondary=key,
        primaryjoin="and_(key.c.entity_id == entity_id, "
            "key.c.key_type_id == 4)",
        secondaryjoin=(key.c.parent_entity_id == entity_id),
        backref=db.backref('key', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')


class Key(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'key'
    ...
    entity_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('entity.entity_id'), nullable=False, 
        index=True)
    ...
    key_type_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('key_type.key_type_id'), index=True) 
        # 4 for a foreign key
    ...
    parent_entity_id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, index=True)
    ...
```

The error traceback is.

```
ipdb> Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-a3063c2d9856>", line 1, in <module>
    debugfile('C:/Users/Mark Kortink/Dropbox/Python/projects/metapplica/_dev/Scraps/ooClass2DBs.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mark Kortink/Dropbox/Python/projects/metapplica/_dev/Scraps')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 856, in debugfile
    debugger.run("runfile(%r, args=%r, wdir=%r)" % (filename, args, wdir))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\bdb.py", line 585, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "c:/users/mark kortink/dropbox/python/projects/metapplica/_dev/scraps/ooclass2dbs.py", line 207, in <module>
    class Entity(db.Model):

  File "c:/users/mark kortink/dropbox/python/projects/metapplica/_dev/scraps/ooclass2dbs.py", line 254, in Entity
    'Entity', secondary=key,

NameError: name 'key' is not defined
```

First am i declaring the backref relationship correctly?
Second how do I break the deadlock?

Comment: You should always include the traceback of the errors that you get in your question as they are useful for identifying the cause of any issues. However, the error that you describe is likely coming from `relationship=key` and `secondaryjoin=(key.c.parent_entity_id == entity_id)`. Make the values of those arguments strings too and they’ll be evaluated after sqlalchemy has finished mapping all of the classes when a reference to those names will exist.

Comment: I have added the traceback to the question. To me iit seems to confirm `key` is not defined (because it is declared after `entity`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `key` doesn't exist in the module you are using. Even if you define your `Key` class first, there would never actually be a reference to the `Table` object named `key` in the scope of your module. In recognition of this, you can pass the name of the table as a string to the arguments of `relationship()` that would otherwise require a reference to that name in your module scope.

From [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship):

> When using the Declarative extension, the Declarative initializer
>   allows string arguments to be passed to relationship(). These string
>   arguments are converted into callables that evaluate the string as
>   Python code, using the Declarative class-registry as a namespace. This
>   allows the lookup of related classes to be automatic via their string
>   name, and removes the need for related classes to be imported into the
>   local module space before the dependent classes have been declared.

That means `secondary=key`, can be declared as `secondary="key"`. SQLAlchemy will then only try to resolve the string `"key"` to the object that it references after all of the classes have been mapped and the table will exist in the internal registry that SQLAlchemy uses to track such objects. Similarly, `secondaryjoin=(key.c.parent_entity_id == entity_id)` can be defined as `secondaryjoin="key.c.parent_entity_id == entity_id"`.